# Setting number of memory banks to 8 on MikroC

Tags: c, pic, mikroc

I am trying to set number of Memory banks in a project to 8 in `#define` at the start of the project but I can't find any way to do it. I am working on `P16F877A`

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? What is a memory bank in your project - a page in an EEPROM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is only this you need, due of lack of information on your question. But to use  `#define` you only have to write like below:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_MEMORY_BANKS (8)
```